# Aplication is not using the wireless or GPRS connection to connect the server

Tags: android, wireless

I've created an application which connects to the "apache tomcat server" through wireless lan.
i connect to an IP address

```
            URL url= new URL("http://192.168.10.143:8080/MyServer/"+"ServletName/");
            urlConn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

***The application works fine on Android emulator but not on actual device.***

The same application which i've developed under J2me is on same principle on java/symbian phone then the  phone asks for connection to be established with the wireless router or GPRS connection.

But on android device there is no response from the device for connecting to the server.
What might be the problem???

I've also put this in AndroidManifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

What else should i do ???

Comment: I cannot make any changes to port as this is company's network.
Please tell me any changes in code or May be some settings on Device???
Thanks for entertaining this noob...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your public IP address, and portforward port: "8080". For more information on how to do that, check out: http://www.portforward.com. There you can find almost any router and how to open a specific port.

Hope that Helps,
Wesley.

Comment: Thanx for the quick replies... I'll try n let u knw.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an internal IP address, which isn't visible outside of your LAN. You need to use a public IP address (this is definitely so for GPRS connection) or adjust your Wi-Fi router so that it provides access to your server.

Comment: mmm... can't say also ive tried to connect to our company's server. but no luck.

Comment: Thanx for the quick replies... I'll try n let u knw.